# Vectorize altazimuth coordinates?

Tags: reference-frames, coordinate-systems, vectors, astronomy, mathematics

Is there a way to convert a pair of altazimuth coordinates (one for each of two observers) into vectors so as to compute the difference between them (i.e. both altazimuth coordinates point at the same object in the sky, and by subtracting the vectors one could obtain a vector between the observers)?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17517/

Comment: Do you want to cord distance or the arc length between them?